Convert to unformatted time in GoogleSheets
Looking for an efficient formula to convert to hh:mm (24 hour time format) in Google Sheets.
When the formatting of a string intended to represent time with AM/PM format is pasted as a value it may, as in line 3 in table below, results in an "automatic" formatting that produces an error when trying to format as hh:mm.



Time
Value




9:30 AM
09:30


10:15 AM
#VALUE!


1:30 PM
13:30



I don't know what format it is in, but Google Sheets aligns the 'corrupt' format to the left, whereas the good format is aligned on the right of the cell as can be seen in the picture.
Error
TIMEVALUE parameter '10:15 AM' cannot be parsed to date/time.

I am curious if there is a simpler or better solution that the one I will post and whether my solution is correct?
Also, curious what the left aligned format is, why it happens when I paste value of cells containing a column with a working format, and how this can be fixed or avoided in future?

20 Things I can't tell from looking at a screenshot of your Sheet

As mentioned above, I am not sure why the improper formatting happens or what it is but this seems to correct for it.
=ARRAYFORMULA(

IFERROR(
IF(A:A="","",
TEXT(
IF((RIGHT(A:A, 2)="PM") * (LEFT(A:A, 2)="12"),
substitute(A:A, right(A:A,3),"") + TIME(0, 0, 0),
IF((RIGHT(A:A, 2)="AM") * (LEFT(A:A, 2)="12"),
substitute("00" & MID(A:A, 3, LEN(A:A)-5), right(A:A,3),"") + TIME(0, 0, 0),
substitute(A:A, right(A:A,3),"") + TIME(12, 0, 0)
)),
"hh:mm"
)
)
)
)
You can then apply  TEXT(B1, "hh:mm AM/PM")to the transformed string and it will evaluate to the specified format (ie 1:00 PM) without reproducing the error.
In other words, this seems to work, but I dont understand the underlying cause of the error.

You should paste a link to a read-only copy of your sheets so we can see which formatting your cells are using. In any case, you should be able to fix it by selecting "Format > Number > Plain text" or "Format > Number > Time".
Or if you want to right-align it, copy either the "9:30 AM" cell or "1:30 PM" cell and paste it into the "10:15 AM" cell and re-type "10:15 AM".
If this worked for you, please mark this answer as "accepted"

I cant because against rules, but now I believe you might acheive something similar if you simply format>number>plaintext

Sharing a sample sheet(with demo data) is NOT against the rules provided that the question satisfies the primary motto of question should be self-contained with markdown table of input/output data along with what you've tried so far. There's also a provision to create a test sheet using the the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account for privacy reasons.

I will come back to this and add. I thought it was against as in past I was down voted and comments referring me to markdown language.
